# Need automated feedback on email groups for non-technical users

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Here's the situation: my church has a bunch of groups, each one led by a different person.  Let's take as an example the choir.

Right now, we've got an Outlook email group set up "choir@my.church" which basically works.  The main problem with this, is that only the Outlook administrator can update the members or even see who is in the group.  The choir director has to email the admin and ask her for the latest list to make sure the group is up-to-date.

We could ask that group leaders (like the choir director) use Outlook for church-related emails, but that's obnoxious because folks really don't like having to check their personal email, plus their church email in a completely separate application.

Most people use g-email, but not all, so even if Google had email groups that would work like we wanted (define them in a central location, but have multiple folks be able to use them), we would have the same problem where the group leaders who don't currently use g-mail would have to check their personal email plus their church g-mail.

**Question - has any company come up with a good solution for this situation?**

The only thought I've come up with is this - when an individual sends a normal email to a group address (like "choir@my.church"), can Outlook be configured so that it automatically sends a reply to that person saying "here is the list of people you just sent the email to"?  This should only happen if:

- the person who sent the email is in the group
- it's the first person sending an email (shouldn't happen for replies)

**Question - can this be done?**

Comment: Sorry, can you more clearly state what you're actually trying to accomplish? The 'can this be done' is... you need folks to be able to automatically generate a (one time only) message containing the membership list of an email group?

Comment: What is your specific purpose? Do you want to see who is in a group before sending a message to a group?

Comment: My initial thought had been, that when someone sends an email to the group (any email, not a special "who's in the group" email), they get this automated response just to confirm what they've done.  But maybe there is a second use case as well, where a user can send some special email to the group (maybe the subject line is "Member Query"), the email doesn't get sent to the group but instead they get a reply with the current membership.

Comment: It sounds like you just want a Google group. Non gmail users can sign up for Google groups, and any member can go to groups.google.com and see the member list of the groups they are in.